# DataTrigger Value Property cannot be specify at design time, what is the alternative way to do it

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatrigger

I have a treeview and click on the each treenode, the detail of the treenode will be displayed to the right side of the treeview. Each treenode has its own viewmodel.The below code showed how I displayed the detail:

When Value="can be specified at designed time" (I have 11 of them), everything is fine. But I have one treenode has the children with different Names (see below code Value="cannot be specified at designed time") because they are retrieved from two columns of a table in the database dynamically and to list 4000 of them or more here wouldn't be realistic.

Name = "J" + tablename.Label + "." + tablename.SubLabel;

```
<ContentControl Name="DetailContentControl" 
Content="{Binding ElementName=myTreeview, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}">
   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl Name="CC" Content="{Binding }" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="DXHeader">
          <Setter TargetName="CC" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource  DXHeaderDetailsTemplate }"/>
      </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"  Value="Don't know at designed time">
    <Setter TargetName="CC" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyDetailsTemplate }"/>
        </DataTrigger>                      
     .....
       </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

If I could do something like this, there would be no issue:

However, DataTrigger.Value property does not support the Binding expression.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When your trigger is based on more than one dynamic value, use a [MultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)

In this case, you'd pass the converter your name and run-time value using bindings, and return something like a true/false value

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsNameEqualValueConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="PathToRuntimeValue" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel,

I made it work by getting rid of the datatrigger and writing a value converter class for the ContentTemplate instead.